# same String is not equal to another

Tags: c#

```
string s =@"&#173;";
string r = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(s);

string r3 = string.Format("1{0}Jan{0}2007",r);
Console.WriteLine(r3);
if(r3 == "1-Jan-2007")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Equal");
    Console.WriteLine("1-Jan-2007");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not Equal");
    Console.WriteLine("1-Jan-2007");

}
```

the Output is

1-Jan-2007
Not Equal
1-Jan-2007

but when i replace r with "-" i.e string.Format("1{0}Jan{0}2007","-");
the Output is

1-Jan-2007
Equal
1-Jan-2007

Comment: What´s the result of String.Compare(r3, "1-Jan-2007") ?

Comment: @ogzd It's true that you need to use .Equals() in java, but in C# it's perfectly fine to use ==.

Comment: `-` is an ASCII character with codepoint <128. `&#173;` is a code-point >127, so they're not the same character, even if they might look similar.

Comment: Far as I can tell, `-` is not ASCII Dec 173.  It's 45.

Comment: @ogzd Why? IMO it looks uglier, and as long as the static type of both sides is `string` (and the left side isn't null) they're equivalent. C# supports operator overloading, and `==` is overloaded on string to use value equality and not reference equality.

Comment: Yup, == is fine, I misthought.

Comment: String.Compare(r3, "1-Jan-2007") result is 1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`&#173;` is the Unicode character 'SOFT HYPHEN' (U+00AD). Although it looks very similar to the Unicode character 'HYPHEN-MINUS' (U+002D), the two characters are not the same.

Comment: then i need to convert SOFT HYPHEN to HYPHEN-MINUS

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(r3.Equals("1-Jan-2007", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```